# How to use Proguard with cordova application when we have to obfuscate plugins logic?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugin-proguard

Is it really possible to use **ProGuard** in **Hybrid Application** I am using Cordova version to build an android app where I have to obfuscate the plugin's java code.

Till now I have done this

Added

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Inside build.gradle of project's root folder.

And uncomment the proguard line from project.properties

proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

But nothing is obfuscating from the code when I decompile the APK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use proguard in cordova android App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27310268/how-to-use-proguard-in-cordova-android-app)

Comment: @AndrewBerry this is not helping me..tried and tested

Comment: https://github.com/greybax/cordova-plugin-proguard